# Some [singular noun]

Tags: word-usage

What word would you use to say *some* as like

> Who took your book? **Some** kid from school.
>
> Wer hat dein Buch genommen? Einiges/Manches Kind aus der Schule.

*Einige* and *manche* just sound very wrong to me here, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I'll add it here since it is missing in the otherwise fin eanswer... einige and manche are plural. It may conjugate as a singular but it always describes a group of items represented by this one individual. Also, genommen is not idiomatic... people would say "weggenommen" or "mitgenommen" or (if with evil intent) "geklaut"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [Irgendein](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/irgendein) Kind aus der Schule.

*Irgendein* means: a specific object from a known selection but you don't particularly know which one.

In plural you would say:

> Ein paar Kinder aus der Schule.

Comment: Don’t know or don’t care. – Other option (colloquial): _so ein Kind_ (_so ’n Kind_).

Answer (score 1):

> - Eines von den Kindern aus der Schule.
> - Eines der Kinder aus der Schule.
> - Irgendwelche Kinder aus der Schule. (Plural)

translates you sentence as well.

Answer (score 0):

In Yiddish we have "eppis a kind vun der schul...".

As an aside, "eppis" is generally considered to be equivalent to *etwas*, but some authorities argue that it derives from "a bis(chen)". I find the latter theory unconvincing because *etwas* is otherwise missing from the Yiddish vocabulary.

Comment: Interesting. In at least some regions of the Palatine, you could say "Ebbes e Kind vun de Schuuhl...", which is almost exactly the same as Yiddish. The Palatine "ebbes" means "etwas".

Comment: *"Ebbes/Eppes"* is not restricted to the Palatine dialect, its quite common in near all southern dialects: http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GE05982